# How to Fake django.contrib.auth User value for specific user?

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I am writing a script and want to fake a User with an `id` (PK) of 2

```
var = Table(FKToUser=2)
var.save()
```

the problem is I'm getting :

```
"Table.FKToUser" must be a "User" instance
```

I've verified that the `auth_user` has a record with `id=2`

How can I fake this `2` value for testing purposes?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `Table` is your model and `FKToUser` is a foreign key, there are two ways. The first is to set the `FKToUser_id` attribute to `2` and save the model. The other is to fetch the user and set the `FKToUser` attribute to the right user model instance.

This is also basically how a foreign key works. The actual column in the database is the `FKToUser_id` column, and it's a simple Integer foreign key to an id in another column. Django magic makes it possible to automatically retrieve the right instance by accessing `FKToUser`, and to set the right value by assigning a model instance to `FKToUser`.

Comment: Firstly - thank you for the answer. Secondly, I'm wondering how can I do the first method you mention? Isn't that what I'm currently trying to do? (By hardcoding a value) ?

Comment: @CodeTalk `var = Table(FKToUser_id=2)`, with the `_id` suffix. Currently you're using a foreign key value where Django expects a model instance. With `_id` is the foreign key value, without `_id` is the model instance.